# Extract code from Adafruit ItsyBitsy 32u4 set up as a HID USB Keyboard

Tags: arduino, adafruit, avrdude

I recently found in my office a suspicious device which I plugged in a spare computer. It was recognized as a keyboard by the system, and started clicking and typing. Whether it is a malicious device, a prank, or an automation tool; I want to find what's it purpose and the code.

When plugged:

```
$ sudo dmesg

[   59.018129] usb 1-4: new full-speed USB device number 5 using xhci_hcd
[   59.169828] usb 1-4: New USB device found, idVendor=239a, idProduct=800e, bcdDevice= 1.00
[   59.169842] usb 1-4: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[   59.169847] usb 1-4: Product: ItsyBitsy 32u4 5V 16MHz
[   59.169851] usb 1-4: Manufacturer: Adafruit
[   59.169855] usb 1-4: SerialNumber: C
[   59.192196] cdc_acm 1-4:1.0: ttyACM0: USB ACM device
[   59.192216] usbcore: registered new interface driver cdc_acm
[   59.192218] cdc_acm: USB Abstract Control Model driver for USB modems and ISDN adapters
[   59.199938] input: Adafruit ItsyBitsy 32u4 5V 16MHz as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-4/1-4:1.2/0003:239A:800E.0002/input/input22
[   59.260993] hid-generic 0003:239A:800E.0002: input,hidraw1: USB HID v1.01 Keyboard [Adafruit ItsyBitsy 32u4 5V 16MHz] on usb-0000:00:14.0-4/input2
[   59.261027] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbhid
[   59.261028] usbhid: USB HID core driver
```

It is a Adafruit ItsyBitsy 32u4. Which has an ATmega32u4 onboard chip and and USB bootloader "AVR109 compatible", according to its description on Adafruit's website.

I know that I cannot get directly the source code but I was planning to use a disassembler to do the translation. And maybe getting some hint about it. Any help about this is also welcome.

I have read that I can dump the binary from the bootloader using the tool `avrdude`. Although, because this device is set as an HID keyboard I do not know if the methods I saw are the appropriate for this or maybe is just impossible to access the bootloader anymore.

I have tried the following:

```
$ sudo avrdude -p m32u4 -c avr109 -U flash:r:flash.hex -v -v
```

- **-p**: type of microcontroller. "m32u4" id for ATmega32u4
- **-c**: programmer to use id.  "avr109"
- **-U**: the memory operation. Read ("r") "flash" ROM of the device into "flash.hex"
- **-v -v**: More verbosity

This is the output (erroneous):

```
          130 ⨯

avrdude: Version 6.3-20171130
         Copyright (c) 2000-2005 Brian Dean, http://www.bdmicro.com/
         Copyright (c) 2007-2014 Joerg Wunsch

         System wide configuration file is "/etc/avrdude.conf"
         User configuration file is "/root/.avrduderc"
         User configuration file does not exist or is not a regular file, skipping

         Using Port                    : /dev/ttyS0
         Using Programmer              : avr109
         AVR Part                      : ATmega32U4
         Chip Erase delay              : 9000 us
         PAGEL                         : PD7
         BS2                           : PA0
         RESET disposition             : dedicated
         RETRY pulse                   : SCK
         serial program mode           : yes
         parallel program mode         : yes
         Timeout                       : 200
         StabDelay                     : 100
         CmdexeDelay                   : 25
         SyncLoops                     : 32
         ByteDelay                     : 0
         PollIndex                     : 3
         PollValue                     : 0x53
         Memory Detail                 :

                                  Block Poll               Page                       Polled
           Memory Type Mode Delay Size  Indx Paged  Size   Size #Pages MinW  MaxW   ReadBack
           ----------- ---- ----- ----- ---- ------ ------ ---- ------ ----- ----- ---------
           eeprom        65    20     4    0 no       1024    4      0  9000  9000 0x00 0x00
           flash         65     6   128    0 yes     32768  128    256  4500  4500 0x00 0x00
           lfuse          0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0  9000  9000 0x00 0x00
           hfuse          0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0  9000  9000 0x00 0x00
           efuse          0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0  9000  9000 0x00 0x00
           lock           0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0  9000  9000 0x00 0x00
           calibration    0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0     0     0 0x00 0x00
           signature      0     0     0    0 no          3    0      0     0     0 0x00 0x00

         Programmer Type : butterfly
         Description     : Atmel AppNote AVR109 Boot Loader

Connecting to programmer: .avrdude: ser_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: butterfly_recv(): programmer is not responding

avrdude: ser_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: butterfly_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: ser_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: butterfly_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: ser_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: butterfly_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: ser_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: butterfly_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: ser_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: butterfly_recv(): programmer is not responding
Found programmer: Id = ""; type = 
    Software Version = .; Hardware Version = .
avrdude: ser_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: butterfly_recv(): programmer is not responding
```

Should I try to add other options? Like **-P** for port, that I have seen in other questions on the internet. Although, I do not know which value to give to this option.

I want to know, it is possible to extract the code from the bootloader? If it is, how? Should I use `avrdude` or any other tool? How?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you are looking for the -P flag, it needs the path to the serial device of the AVR when it's in its bootloader.  As long as it is a normal itsybitsy, and not one that's been modified to work without the bootloader, you need to get it into the bootloader by hitting the reset button twice withing 750ms, and within 8 seconds you need to run the avrdude command.

For the -P flag, you posted your dmesg output, and it's the same as my machine, /dev/ttyACM0.

So, my dance to get mine is to hold reset for a count of 5 (to let Linux notice it's gone and free the device it was assigned), hit the reset button again quickly, wait for a second (but not too long; Linux needs to reallocate the tty but you cannot miss the bootloader window), then run the avrdude command:

```
sudo avrdude -p m32u4 -c avr109 -P /dev/ttyACM0 -U flash:r:flash.hex -v -v
```

Good luck!  Hopefully it's just a prank.

Comment: It worked. As soon as I plugged it, I hit the reset button twice within a second (I guess 750ms) and the LED started blinking slowly. In this window I executed the command and obtained the flash.hex file. Thank you!